# clockwise angle between two line

Tags: c#, geometry, drawing, 2d, computational-geometry

I want to calculate a clockwise angle between two line segment A and B. So the resulting angle must be between 0 to 360-1 degrees. I've seen all other answers in SO but they gave me negative angles. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For turning any angle into a 0-359 range in C#, you can use the following "algorithm":

```
public int Normalise (int degrees) {
    int retval = degrees % 360;
    if (retval < 0)
        retval += 360;
    return retval;
}
```

C# follows the same rules as C and C++ and `i % 360` will give you a value between `-359` and `359` for any integer, then the second line is to ensure it's in the range 0 through 359 inclusive.

A sneaky version on one line:

```
    degrees = ((degrees % 360) + 360) % 360;
```

which would normalise it under all conditions. I'm not sure I'd worry too much about using the inline one-liner unless performance was critical, but I *will* explain it.

From `degrees % 360`, you will get a number between `-359` and `359`. Adding `360` will modify the range to between `1` and `729`. Then the final `% 360` will bring it back to the range `0` through `359`.

Answer (score 2):

I would try :

```
if degrees is between [-360, 360]
    degrees = (degrees + 360) % 360;
else degrees = (degrees % 360) + 360) % 360;
```

Answer (score 1):

Surely you could adapt any solution with negative angles to always be 0-360 by adjusting:

float positive = (angle < 0) ? (360 + angle) : angle